# ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster:Unable to connect to any servers, AuthenticationFailed

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, cassandra-2.1

I am seeing this error in Opscenterd.log Opscenter version 5.2.3

2016-07-10 11:04:01-0400 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'xx.xxx.xx.xx': AuthenticationFailed(u'Failed to authenticate to xx.xxx.xx.xx: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Username and/or password are incorrect"',)})

but the username and password in cluster.conf are correct couldn't identify what causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this OpsCenter Knowledgebase article below:

https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/211249143-Opscenter-unable-to-connect-with-Bad-credentials-error-message

Let me know if this helps.